# Uniqueness of the Laplace Transformation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

Today; when I was doing some Inverse Laplace transformation in the class, I encountered the following problem cited in Zill's book:

> The inverse Laplace transformation may be not **unique**. In Problems 29 and 30 evaluate $\mathscr{L}\{f(t)\}$.
>
> **29.** $f(t) = \left\{
>         \begin{array}{ll}
>             1, & \quad t\ge0,~ t\ne1, t\ne2 \\
>             3, & \quad t=1 \\
>             4, & \quad t=2 \\
>         \end{array}
>     \right.$
>
> **30.** $f(t) = \left\{
>         \begin{array}{ll}
>             \text{e}^{3t}, & \quad t\ge0,~ t\ne 5, \\
>             1, & \quad t=5
>         \end{array}
>     \right.$

I did them, but I was wondered how to explain the students if they ask me about the criteria for the uniqueness. I think it is rooted in the functional analysis, however, I am weak in this area. Is there any easier way to explain the uniqueness for second year graduate students? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Undergraduate, I mean. :-)

Comment: Babak S: ✿Nice Question✿

Comment: @Babk : for second year undergrads, I would just say that for the purposes of Laplace transforms, Fourier series, Fourier transforms, etc., we consider functions to be equivalent if they differ on only a finite number of points (or a finite number of points per period in the case of Fourier series).  When you do the integrals to compute their Laplace transforms, etc., you get the same results.

Comment: @StefanSmith: Thanks so much for the advices. I'll do that. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue here is continuity, since you typically cannot hope to recover the behavior of a function at a point which is not a point of continuity from an integral transform.  If you consider continuous functions which decay fast enough (for example, subexponentially decaying functions) then you can prove uniqueness fairly easily by a standard calculation.  For example, see [here](http://web.mit.edu/jorloff/www/18.03-esg/notes/laplaceuniqueness.pdf).

Comment: Tanks so much Chris. I got the way. You are a good tutor. :-)

Comment: Unfortunately the link no longer works.